# Why a webpage with a suffix .asp cannot be open in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsp, internet-explorer

I tried to browse a webpage "https://aeropdm.honeywell.com/aeroPDM/emxLogin.jsp". But it cannot be opened in Chrome but run nomally in IE11. Is it the problem that Chrome do not support some technology of java's jsp?

Comment: Modified my answer, please check if this is what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser has nothing to do with server side languages, So there is no matter of java/jsp. Browser render front end content provided by server in form of html.

After viewing source code of your page I found the issue.

In your html code you kept your division hidden-

```
<div style="visibility:hidden" id="divLogin">
```

and once page is loaded you are enabling it by calling **handleOnLoad()** function

```
 <body bgColor=#ffffff 
        background="/aeroPDM/common/images/utilSpacer.gif"
         onload="handleOnLoad()">
```

Now this function  **handleOnLoad()**  is setting content visible.

If you see **handleOnLoad()**, it is setting this content visible for IE and Moz and Netscape I guess but not for other browsers

```
 function handleOnLoad() {

 //display the login form (only happens if JavaScript is enabled)
 if (isNS4) {
         setTimeout("void(0)",10);
         document.layers['layerLogin'].visibility = "show";
  } else if (isIE) {
         document.all['divLogin'].style.visibility =  "visible";
  } else if (isMoz) { 
         document.getElementById('divLogin').style.visibility = "visible";
 }
```

So to make it visible in other browsers, You can simple add 1 line for all chrome in last.

```
else
document.getElementById('divLogin').style.visibility = "visible";
```

So in short you just need to replace your **handleOnLoad()** javascript function
with this -

```
function handleOnLoad() {

 //display the login form (only happens if JavaScript is enabled)
 if (isNS4) {
         setTimeout("void(0)",10);
         document.layers['layerLogin'].visibility = "show";
  } else if (isIE) {
         document.all['divLogin'].style.visibility =  "visible";
  } else if (isMoz) { 
         document.getElementById('divLogin').style.visibility = "visible";
  else
  document.getElementById('divLogin').style.visibility = "visible";
  }
```

last else will execute for every browser other thank NS,IE and Mozilla, So if you want it to work for chrome only then please append some condition with `else` and make it `else if`.

**Hope this will solve your issue.**

Comment: Thanks bro. Your explaination is correct but extend to another question: Why set the div's visibility to 'hidden' by default? Why not shows the div dircectly?

Comment: May be becoz login page aims at submit Form which should use JavaScript. So the developer detect if JavaScript is enabled firsly. If not, then hidden the content 'rudely' ?

Comment: Yes may be developer don't want to show division in case page is not loaded fully, if you find my answer correct, please mark it as answer. Thanks